How can I use yarn portal dependencies from different folder levels in my monorepo?
I'm trying to use portals in my monorepo with Yarn 4.1.0 and it can't resolve a common dependency when it is referred to from parent directories which are nested differently in the monorepo, even though they refer to literally the same folder.
The folder hierarchy is like:
├───main
├───modules
│   ├───AAA
│   ├───BBB


main/package.json refers to BBB as "portal:../modules/BBB"
modules/AAA/package.json refers to BBB as "portal:../BBB"

Because main depends on both AAA and BBB, and AAA depends on BBB.

main depends on [ AAA, BBB ]
AAA depends on [ BBB ]
BBB depends on [] (nothing)

But Yarn thinks that ~/main/../modules/BBB and ~/modules/AAA/../BBB are not the same file.
How can I get yarn to stop complaining about a conflict and use portals correctly?
The actual error:
During yarn install in ~/main. (with anonymized module names below:)

YN0071: │ Cannot link @modules/AAA into main@workspace:. dependency @modules/BBB@portal:../BBB::locator=%40modules%2FAAA%40portal%3A..%2Fmodules%2FAAA%3A%3Alocator%3Dmain%2540workspace%253A. conflicts with parent dependency @modules/BBB@portal:../modules/BBB::locator=main%40workspace%3A.

in main/package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@modules/AAA": "portal:../modules/AAA",
    "@modules/BBB": "portal:../modules/BBB",

in modules/AAA/package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@modules/BBB": "portal:../BBB",


I had this same problem and I resolved it by using the resolutions field in the main package's package.json.
In your case it might look like this:
{
  dependencies: {
    "@modules/BBB": "portal:../modules/BBB"
  },
  resolutions: {
    "@modules/BBB": "portal:../modules/BBB"
  }
}

This ensures that any transitive dependencies on package @modules/BBB that may refer to it by a different path are instead always resolved according to the main package's path to it.
